# Push notification mechanism used by other apps in Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, push-notification, windows-phone-7.1, mqtt, mpns

I want to know what push mechanism does gmail, facebook or other common apps use in Windows Phone? Are they using MPNS only or something else (like MQTT). For example, Facebook is available for all platforms so whether they are using different protocols for different platforms or using a common approach.

I want to implement push notification for my app. The same app is being developed for other platforms like Android and iPhone also. So I want to use a mechanism which can be used across platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com), it provides support for `Microsoft Windows Phone 8` and `Windows 8` push through MPNS and WNS, but doesn't support MPNS push to `Windows Phone 7` devices

- Docs for .net http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/build_push.html#windows
- Docs for iOS http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/build_push.html#ios
- Docs for Android http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/build_push.html#android

Or [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) which requires more work

- API for .net http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/
- API for iOS http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/
- API for Android http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Answer (score 1):

You should think of Push Notifications as a transport channel, not more. Each mobile platform (Apple, Google, Microsoft) uses it's own cloud to reach your device, and that's could be enough. Once reached, your mobbile app may do whatever it need (for example, to grab extra details about the notification as size of Push message is usually limited).

Given that in mind, it's not a big deal to create one server app communicating to 3 different clouds if sending notifications.